# Prevent NPM install from removing symlinked node_modules directory

Tags: npm, symlink

I use a deployment service to push my LEMP app's code; I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 / AWS. I've installed Node via NVM and am using Node v19.6.1 & NPM v9.4.0

- My deployment process uses symlinking to map a `/current/` directory to
  the latest release.
- I also have a `/shared/` directory that stays in
  place for assets that either A) don't need to change B) should say
  centralized.
- The shared directory houses things like `/node_modules/`;
  the primary reason for doing things like this is to prevent a bunch
  of releases having duplicated `/node_modules/` folders taking up space in
  different release directories.

---

1. I've run the following to create my symlink
   `sudo ln -sv /var/www/mysite/html/shared/assets/node_modules /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/node_modules`
2. I see the symlink when I do `/var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/ && ls -la`
3. When I run the following, npm removes my symlink
   `cd /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/ && npm i`

Specifically running npm i starts by literally saying it's removing my symlink; ***I want it to keep the symlink...but install the files in my symlink destination.***

`npm WARN reify Removing non-directory /var/www/mysite/html/releases/####/assets/node_modules`

In the past, I'm pretty sure that I've had my node_modules directory symlinked, have been able to run `npm i` in the directory where the symlink exists, and my files get installed in the symlink destination folder.

I've also tried `npm link`

4. From within my shared directory, I've created the symlink for my package.json file (if I don't do this npm link outputs an error)
   `sudo ln -sv /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/package.json /var/www/mysite/html/shared/assets/node_modules/package.json`
5. Then I run cd /var/www/mysite/html/shared/assets/node_modules/ && npm link
   Lastly I run `cd /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/ <my-project-name>`; this seems like it's running npm, but this doesn't seem to actually install anything.

As a workaround I've just done:

6. Install npm, move it, and then symlink it

`cd /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/ && npm i`
`sudo mv /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/node_modules /var/www/mysite/html/shared/assets/node_modules`
`sudo ln -sv /var/www/mysite/html/shared/assets/node_modules /var/www/mysite/html/current/assets/node_modules`

...but that just feels wrong / weird

My questions

1. Has removing the node_modules folder / symlink something that is in newer versions of npm that wasn't in older versions?
2. How can I:
   A) symlink my node_modules folder
   B) keep my symlink when using npm
   C) make sure that my files get installed into the symlink destination directory?
3. Is there a best-practice / something obvious here that I'm missing?

Comment: 1. You only get to ask one question, not 3, so please fix that. 2. You really shouldn't be sharing the node_modules folder as each release *may* have different dependencies (even if it's only version differences). Your shared folder approach means that when you update node_modules (though a change in package.json) you're updating your other releases too, which may break them. Storage is cheap these days, you don't really need to optimise it that much. The best practice that you're missing is not sharing node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `node_modules` if it's a symlink and replacing it with a directory is behaviour that was introduced in npm 7.20.6 to prevent a certain class of security vulnerabilities.

Based on the discussion in the [npm github issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3669) there are no great work-arounds or suitable configuration possible for this behaviour. Using the `--force` argument has too many other drawbacks, notably re-downloading all resources always.

To address your specific requirements, namely saving space usually wasted by multiple release directories, consider implementing your normal `node_modules` symlink approach with [`yarn`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/), or switch to [`pnpm`](https://pnpm.io/), which will by default use hardlinks / reflinks to de-duplicate between all of your projects.

I have just confirmed that both the latest yarn classic (1.22.19) and pnpm 8.6.0 preserve one's `node_modules` symlink.